# Flutter dynamic bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

In my Project i have 4 screens.

Home - Help Center - Search - Profile.

**In Home page:** My AppBar has leading and action buttons without title and transparent.

[image]

**In Help Center** My AppBar has leading doesnt have action buttons has a title and its a custom appbar.

[image]

**In Search Screen** : Using same appbar as help center screen but has action buttons and leading.

**My Question is:** As you can understand in my app i using few diffrent appbars. So how can i connect that bottomNavigationBar dynamicly ? Appbars isn't same thats why i cant use bottomNavigationBar for now.
So what can i do about it ? How can i make it dynamic ? Thanks for all responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by connecting bottomNavigationBar?
I did not understand what your problem is completely, but if you want that bottom nav bar is common for your all pages you can use this approach:

```
//class variable
final _screens = [
  const Page1(),
  const Page2(),
  const Page3(),
];

//your start page
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      _screens[_currentIndex],
      //some code
    ],
  ),
);
```

And you can change _currentIndex by tapping your nav bar items. For more help you can share some code parts of your app and explanation.

Comment: thanks for reply. I get how can i make it now. But can i ask 1 more question ? I did for appbars too like : 

`appBar:_appBarOptions[_selectedIndex],`

But i want to change state inside of that appbars. (for change currentIndex.) So how can i change currentindex in that list of appbars ?

https://prnt.sc/JR59OF6eW18G  U can understand better with that image.

Comment: okay man i made it. Instead of List i made a Function with switch case and its fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I am happy to help, have a good day.